# Send cases entity data in a table format in my email from email router in CRM Dynamics 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have succeded in sending email on each case entity update/edit thru' email router from my CRM dynamics 2011 account.

Now i want to send all my cases entity data present in my CRM server DB in a table format in the email body.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

The email entity is based in html so you can add images, tables, etc. and you can add dynamic values based in a entity. You can see [here](http://elvenprogrammer.themanaworld.org/stunning-html-rich-emails-dynamics-crm-2011/) a very good tutorial about html and how put the values dynamically. If you want send an email via plugin you need add a email template and use them to send the email. Check [here](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/08/02/creating-an-email-template-is-quick-and-easy-in-crm-2011/) how create a email template.